# mysql query help to fetch data by joining multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I have following tables:

base:
`id | domain`

extended:
`id | domain | country_code`

countries:
`id | country_code | country_name`

banned_domains:
`id | domain`

I will have several thousands (more than 500K) of domains in banned_domains. Now I need to fetch data "domain, country_code and country_name" which do not exist on banned_domains list. I am not so good at the MySQL JOINS, can anyone guide me for the proper query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT b.domain, ex.country_code, c.country_name FROM base b 
INNER JOIN extended ex ON b.domain=ex.domain
INNER JOIN countries c ON ex.country_code=c.country_code
WHERE b.domain NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM banned_domains);
```

Comment: I will have several thousands (more than 500K) of domains in banned_domains. Will `WHERE b.domain NOT IN (SELECT domain FROM banned_domains)` create a problems?

Comment: It shouldn't, but if that is your concern, why not update the base table, adding a column to flag if the domain is banned?

Comment: The application works that way and need to have a single table for banned domains where user can pre-specify banned domains.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this query .

```
select b.domain , e.country_code , c.country_name from base b join  extended e on b.domain = e.domain join countries c on e.country_code = c.country_code and b.domain not in (select domain from banned_domains);
```

Try this link http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f78ea/1 .

Comment: Did you noticed the output? The output for domain is 'google.com' for all results.

Comment: Yes I noticed this . How can you get the specified results without country_code , country_name in banned_domains table .Can you post is there any relationship between countries , banned_domains table?

Comment: No there is not any relation between countries and banned_domains table. I only need the data "domain, country_code and country_name" for domains that do not exist on banned_domains table.

Comment: @Prakash , I editted my query . Is this output you excepted ?